# Enabling Steam Family Sharing

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing

I'm trying to share my steam library but Valve seems to have updated their interface without updating their docs.

Every Tutorial I look at features the settings window with a horizontal tab bar, mine has a vertical list and no "Authorize" button.

[image]

I've been on the Beta Channel for years and the client updates regularly.

[image]

Has anyone been able to enable family sharing through the new interface?

**Edit**: I am logging into both accounts from the same PC.

Comment: I haven't done it on the new interface, but are you have to actually log into the computer you're sharing to. You can't just share to an account.

Comment: I am logging into both accounts from the same PC, I should have specified that.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When this question was asked, Steam Family Sharing was in beta.  However, as of March 3rd 2014, Steam Family Sharing is [out of beta](http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2014/03/03/all-in-the-steam-family-sharing-available-to-everyone/) and available to everyone.

If you open that tab now, you should see a screen like this:

[image: Steam family sharing]