# Steam Transfer Help

Tags: steam

Can I transfer 2 accounts into one. I have an account that has all my money. But I accidentally used another account and that one has all my status. Can I transfer them both into one?

Comment: Google search: [share Steam library](https://www.google.com/search?q=share+steam+library&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try contacting steam support. But you'll have to prove you own both of them and there's no guarantee.

Comment: I had friends try this. Support gave negative replies to them in all cases.

Answer (score 7):

No, you can't combine steam accounts.

You can buy items/games on one and gift/trade it to the other one though.

You can also try [Steam Family Sharing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/154784/enabling-steam-family-sharing).