# Steam sharing an account

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam

Is there a way that me and my friend can share the same account but have separate saves. A way to play the same games at the same time but to have different views. We have been trying to play skyrim but we have the same saves and its really annoying.

Comment: No.  Sharing accounts is against Steam's terms of service.

Comment: Have a look at [family sharing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/154784/enabling-steam-family-sharing?rq=1)

Comment: @3ventic This should be written up as an answer as it provides a very clear solution to the problem, with bonus "Thinking outside of the box" points.

Answer (score 9):

Steam accounts are personal and should not be shared, but you can use [Family Sharing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/154785/51318) to authorize other Steam accounts on the same computer to use most games in your Steam library while you're not playing yourself.